# GRE geometry question: Determining whether one area is greater or equal to another

Tags: geometry, solution-verification

This problem was in my GRE practice textbook
[image]

Their answer was that the two quantities are equal, but I keep on getting a different answer. Let $\overline{BC} = y $ and $\overline{AE}=x$. Then it follows that the diagonal of the square $BCDF$ is equal to $x$. Therefore, we can use the pythagorean theorem to see that $y^2 + y^2 = x^2 \rightarrow x = \sqrt{2}y$. Therefore, the area of $ABDE$ is $x^2=2y^2$ and the area of $BCDF$ is $y^2$. Multiply $ABDE$ by two to get $4y^2$ and multiply the area of $BCDF$ by three to get $3y^2$. Therefore it should be that twice the area of $ABDE$ is greater than three times the area of $BCDF$, but this is not correct. What error am I making here?

Comment: shaded region excludes the triangle BDF.

Comment: ah you are right, completely went autopilot. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is in comparing the areas of the squares, but what the question is asking for is comparing the area of the **shaded region** (Quantity A) against the area of the white square.

The simpler way to solve this question is to observe that drawing the diagonal $BD$ of square $BCDF$, and continuing the sides $DF$ to $A$ and $BF$ to $E$, partitions the figure into five congruent isosceles triangles.  Two of these triangles (in white) comprise the square $BCDF$, and three of these (shaded) comprise the total area of the shaded figure.  The comparison then becomes trivial.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let the edge length of the square (bottom) be $x$.

So, the height and base length of the triangle $BDF$ are $\frac{x}{2}$ and $x$ respectively.

Area of shaded region, $$A_1 = x^2 - \frac{1}{2}.\frac{x^2}{2} = \frac{3x^2}{4}$$

Now, for the square $CDFB$, $BD$ acts as a diagonal. So, $$CD = \  \frac{x}{\sqrt2} $$

Area of upper square, $$A_2 = (\frac{x}{\sqrt2})^2 = \frac{x^2}{2}$$

So, $$2A_1 = \frac{3x^2}{2} = 3A_2$$